# Ground type for DC regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator, pcb-design, ground-plane

When considering a simple DC regulator such as a Texas' LM22677 on a PCB, should it use the digital or analog portion of the ground plane?

EDIT: Contextualizing, I have a 12V input feeding two LM22677 regulators to achieve a 5V and 10V power lines. The 5V is then used to power and Arduino, and the 5V/GND output of the Arduino is then used to power several analog/digital ICs. Should the ground plane of the DC regulators be common to the rest of the circuitry, or should it be separate?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Question about analog and digital ground planes](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/97927/question-about-analog-and-digital-ground-planes)

Comment: You normally use split ground plane for a very sensitive analog portion.  But the part you mention is a 5A switching regulator. This is an unusual juxtaposition.  Which is more important, low noise or massive switching regulator?

Answer (score 3):

If the regulator is for feeding to digital stuff then use the digital ground plane. If it feeds analogue circuits then tie it via one good PCB trace to the analogue ground. If it's mixed signal then it all depends on how you have designed the two ground planes.